# "maximum number of people and Pages to see first" - What is the limit and how to trim list?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

- What is the limit as the message did not say anything about that
- How to trim the list for the ones I want there to avoid message

> **You've Reached the Limit**
>   You have picked the maximum number of people and Pages to see first. You need to remove one before you can add District Crossfit.

[image: http://prntscr.com/anvkv6]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**What is See First:** When you select a person or Page to see first, their posts appear at the top of your News Feed.

**Limit:** You can select up to 30 people or Pages to see first.

For more see the [Help Centre](https://www.facebook.com/help/1188278037864643).

***Edit after OPs' comment***
How to clear items from the list?

From [Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/371675846332829):

> To view your News Feed preferences:
>
> 1. Click 'v' in the top-right corner of any Facebook page.
> 2. Select News Feed Preferences
>
> To adjust your News Feed preferences:
>
> - Click Prioritize who to see first to make posts from people or Pages appear at the top of your News Feed. Learn about [see first](https://www.facebook.com/help/1188278037864643).
> - Click Unfollow people to hide their posts to unfollow a person, Page or group. Learn about [unfollowing](https://www.facebook.com/help/190078864497547).
> - Click Reconnect with people you unfollowed to follow a person, Page or group that you unfollowed in the past. Learn about [reconnecting](https://www.facebook.com/help/146865632052048).
>
> Learn how to switch from [top stories to most recent stories](https://www.facebook.com/help/218728138156311) on your News Feed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you help add further on how to clear items from the list?

Comment: @AlexS: Edited answer.

Comment: I went to this link and with this method cant see a "list" that I can undo from. With this method, I need to remember which pages are on my SeeFirst list before I can go there and remove them. Is there a way to see a list and delete / unfollow SeeFirst pages from it?

Comment: Add more detailed steps {as it was a bit unclear} to the answer you got from FB help